# Express install err

Tags: node.js, termux

I want to install express in my project on termux but I keep getting this error

```
npm install --save express

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall symlink
npm ERR! path ../mime/cli.js
npm ERR! dest /storage/emulated/0/php/node-crash-course/node_modules/.bin/mime
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/php/node-crash-course/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, symlink '../mime/cli.js' -> '/storage/emulated/0/php/node-crash-course/node_modules/.bin/mime'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'symlink',
npm ERR!   path: '../mime/cli.js',
npm ERR!   dest: '/storage/emulated/0/php/node-crash-course/node_modules/.bin/mime'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.
```

Comment: try [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/WSL/issues/26#issuecomment-636041892)

Comment: try `chmod -R 755 /storage/emulated/0/php/node-crash-course` before installing, or `sudo npm install --save express`

Comment: The first method give the same error

Comment: The second method output: No superuser binary detected.
Are you rooted?